# How can I append a group after having it linked earlier?

Tags: linked-data, append

I linked a group in from another file, it was a character with armature. After linking it I realize that I don't have control over the armature so I deleted it and decided that I want to append it in instead. But it just won't appear after appending. I tried other groups, in different files, it appears that this is persistent. I can't append any group as long as I have: 1. linked it 2. then delete it.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you upload your .blend?

Comment: How do I upload?

Comment: Upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1209" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1209/) Here is the working file, I will upload the group source file now.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1210" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1210/) Now here is the source file where I created a group to be appended. I have already linked it and delete it like I said. Problem has been recreated, I can't append the group anymore. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I supposed this is a known bug and an example of blender's bad data management, as when you delete a linked model, you still have lingering data that somehow prevents blender from appending the same model again.

Comment: I have tested and can reproduce this in 2.77a. Very strange behavior indeed.

Comment: It's 2018, and this is happening in 2.79.3. Not sure if this is a bug... it's most likely I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Praise God for showing me a solution! I have posted the solution here in this old developer thread: https://developer.blender.org/T44890

Comment: @Copperplate I reopened, you can answer now.

Comment: Thanks, David! I just posted an even simpler answer that has been tested to work. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a very simple solution of how to append a group after having previously linked it in or how to simply get rid of an unwanted group instance:

1. In the Outliner, switch to "Blender File", and open up "Libraries".

[image: Append Group after Linking_Step 1]

2. Right click the library referencing the linked group, and press "Delete".

[image: Append Group after Linking_Step 2]

You will now be able to immediately append the group as normal, no saving or re-opening required!